# Desktop background won't change until restart

Tags: 11.10, desktop-background

I'm new to Ubuntu and indeed Linux systems.

I have 11.04 installed on my laptop. Here's the problem. When i select a picture for the desktop background, it says that Desktop Background has been changed but the changes do not apply right away. It is only after I have restarted the system that the changes will appear.

This did not happen before. When i first started using this OS a few months ago the changes applied immediately. So what have i done that made this start acting wonky.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried logging out and logging back in first? The issue may be session-based versions a complete restart of the system, and that would be better to try first, to determine if the problem is based on the session rather than restarting the entire system (which in Linux should not be required).

Normally, the change should apply automatically, but this may be a problem with your session, hard to tell without more information at present. Have you added or made any changes to the desktop session, in other words modifications to items such as Unity or GNOME-Shell?